# Revert to default math font with Koma

Tags: math-mode, fonts, default

I'm using a Koma-based class provided by my university. For some reason however the standard Latex math font is replaced by the following:

[image]

Any idea how to revert to the default one?
I suspect the change is hiding somewhere in the class definition:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{amu_these}[2020/06/04 Classe personnelle, V0.9]

%%% classe de base (KOMA-Script)
\LoadClass{scrreprt}                        %% classe report KOMA-Script
\KOMAoptions{
    paper=a4,                               %% taille du papier
    fontsize=12pt,                          %% taille de la police
    DIV=12,                                 %% taille des marges
    BCOR=0mm,                               %% taille de la reliure
    twoside=off,                            %% recto-verso
    listof=totoc,                           %% LOFT dans la TOC
    index=totoc                             %% index dans la TOC
    }

%\RequirePackage{lipsum}                        %% lorem ipsum (exemple)

%%% extensions minimales
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %% encodage du texte
\RequirePackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}            %% encodage des fontes
%\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage[french,main=english]{babel} %% typographie (anglais par défaut)
\RequirePackage[babel]{csquotes}            %% guillemets typographiques
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}                        %% espacement automatique des guillemets

%%% typographie et mise en page
\RequirePackage{scrhack}                    %% macros personnalisées (KOMA-Script)
\RequirePackage[
    automark,                               %% rappel du titre de chapître en en-tête
    autooneside=false                       %% nécessaire pour le rappel du chapître et de la partie en en-tête
    ]{scrlayer-scrpage}                     %% en-tête/pied de page personnalisés (KOMA-Script)
\RequirePackage{textcomp}                   %% symboles complémentaires
\RequirePackage{hyphenat}                   %% césure explicite
\RequirePackage{microtype}                  %% microtypographie

\RequirePackage[bottom=10em]{geometry}      %% réduit le bas de page pour pouvoir numéroter les pdf insérés (réduire plus si nécessaire)
\RequirePackage{setspace}                   %% modification de l'interligne

\pagestyle{scrheadings}                     %% style de page
%\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}       %% titrage en police sérif (décommenter)
%\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\bfseries}  %% entrée des glossaires en police sérif (décommenter)

%%% tableaux et figures
\RequirePackage{float}                      %% définit les objets flottants tels que les figures et tableaux
\RequirePackage{graphicx}                   %% graphiques et figures
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}          %% permet de définir une taille minimale ou maximale
\RequirePackage{subfig}                     %% figures multiples
\RequirePackage{caption}                    %% légendes des figures
\RequirePackage{tabularx}                   %% tableaux
\RequirePackage{multirow}                   %% fusion des cellules dans les tableaux 
\RequirePackage{makecell}                   %% sauts des lignes dans les cellules   
\RequirePackage{fourier}                    %% fusion des lignes dans les tableaux 
\RequirePackage{array}                      %% amélioration des tableaux
\RequirePackage{booktabs}                   %% tables formelles
\RequirePackage{tikz}                       %% figures en code natif
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

%\floatplacement{figure}{H}                 %% placer une figure là où elle a été appelée
\graphicspath{{fig/}{logo/}}                %% chemins vers fichiers images

%%% appareil de référence (sauf glossaires)
\PassOptionsToPackage{                      %% options biblatex
    backend=biber,                          %% compilateur par défaut pour biblatex
    maxnames=3,                             %% nombre max. de noms auteurs
    minnames=1,                             %% nombre min. de noms auteurs
    sorting=nyt,                            %% trier par nom, année, titre
    citestyle=authoryear,                   %% style de citation auteur-année
    bibstyle=alphabetic,                    %% style de bibliographie alphabétique
%   bibstyle=iso-authoryear,                %% style de bibliographie ISO 690
    backref=true                            %% liens retour des références (cf. p.)
    }
    {biblatex}
\RequirePackage{biblatex}                   %% gestion de la bibliographie avec biblatex
\RequirePackage{enotez}                     %% notes de fin
\setenotez{
    list-name=Notes,                        %% titre des notes
    totoc=chapter,                          %% niveau des notes dans la TOC
    backref                                 %% hyperlien retour des notes
    }
\RequirePackage{imakeidx}                   %% index
\RequirePackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}  %% fonctions pour TOC LOF LOT
\RequirePackage{etoc}                       %% fonctions pour TOC locale (préférable à minitoc avec KOMA-Script)
%\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}                      %% ajoute la TOC à la TOC
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Sommaire]{%     %% définit une commande pour la TOC locale (Sommaire)
    \etocsetnexttocdepth{3}%                %% profondeur de la TOC locale
    \etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1}}{}%
    \localtableofcontents%
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}                 %% profondeur des sections numérotées
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}                    %% profondeur des sections dans la table des matières

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}                 %% fichiers sources bibliographiques
\makeindex[                                 %% génère l'index
    program=makeindex,                      %% compilateur
    options=-s these,                       %% paramètres
    columns=1,                              %% nombre de colonnes
    intoc                                   %% index dans la TOC
    ]

%%% mathématiques, physique, chimie (à adapter)
\RequirePackage{amsmath}                    %% formules mathématiques
\RequirePackage{amssymb}                    %% symboles mathématiques
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}                   %% polices mathématiques

\RequirePackage{xspace}                     %% gestions des espaces dans les macros
\RequirePackage{xparse}                     %% macros avancées
\RequirePackage{nicefrac}                   %% fractions en ligne (voir aussi xfrac)
\RequirePackage{siunitx}                    %% unités du système international
\sisetup{                                   %% options pour les unités
    list-final-separator = { \translate{and} }, 
    list-pair-separator  = { \translate{and} },
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    exponent-product = {\cdot},
    separate-uncertainty = true
    }
\PassOptionsToPackage{version=4}{mhchem}
%\RequirePackage{mhchem}                        %% chimie

%\RequirePackage{physics}                   %% physique

%%% PDF
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}                   %% insertion de pdf
\RequirePackage{hyperref}                   %% pdf interactifs (charger le package hyperref en dernier)

\pdfminorversion=5                          %% PDF en version 1.5
\pdfobjcompresslevel 0                      %% compression des objets
\pdfcompresslevel 0                         %% compression du PDF

\hypersetup{
    %backref=true,                          %% ajout de liens (par défaut)
    %pagebackref=true,                      %% dans la bibliographie (par défaut)
    %hyperindex=true,                       %% dans l'index (par défaut)
    %bookmarks=true,                        %% signets Acrobat (par défaut)
    breaklinks=true,                        %% retour à la ligne (si lien trop long)
    colorlinks=true,                        %% colorise liens
    urlcolor=blue,                          %% couleur hyperliens
    citecolor=blue,                         %% couleur liens bibliographie
    linkcolor=blue,                         %% couleur liens internes
    anchorcolor=blue,                       %% couleur liens ancres
    bookmarksopen=false,                    %% signets repliés par défaut
    linktocpage=false,                      %% lien numéro de page dans TOC
%% métadonnées :                            %% ATTENTION à compléter
    pdftitle={Titre},
    pdfauthor={Prénom NOM},
    pdfsubject={Résumé},
    pdfkeywords = {mot clé, keyword, ...},
    }

%%% glossaires
\RequirePackage[
    acronym,                                %% liste des acronymes
    xindy,                                  %% compilateur xindy
    toc,                                    %% affichage dans la TOC
    style=altlist                           %% affichage des entrées
    ]
    {glossaries}                            %% glossaires (charger le package glossaries après le package hyperref)
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Nomenclature} % Création d'un type de glossaire 'notation'
%\makeglossaries                                %% génère les glossaires
%\loadglsentries{tex/gloss}                 %% fichiers sources glossaires


\newcommand{\langue}{\emph}                 
\newcommand{\citital}{\emph}                

\newcommand{\acc}{\ensuremath{\omega ^{2}=\omega ^{2}_{0}+2\alpha \theta}\xspace}
\newcommand{\emiss}[2][]{\ensuremath{\varepsilon_{#2}^{#1}}\xspace}

%%% commandes pour la page de titre
\definecolor{blueamu}{RGB}{0, 101, 189}
\definecolor{cyanamu}{RGB}{61, 183, 228}

\newcommand{\dhorline}[3][0]{%
    \tikz[baseline=-2pt]{\path[decoration={markings, 
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2*#3
      with {\node[color=blueamu, fill, circle, minimum width=#3, inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] {};}},postaction={decorate}]  (0,#1) -- ++(#2,0);}}
\newcommand{\dvertline}[3][0]{%
    \tikz[baseline=2em]{\path[decoration={markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2*#2
      with {\node[color=black!50, fill, circle, minimum width=#2, inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] {};}},postaction={decorate}] (0, #1) -- ++(0,#3);}}

\newcommand\titel[1]{{\usefont{T1}{tit}{el}{n} #1 }}
\newcommand\titl[1]{{\usefont{T1}{tit}{l}{n} #1 }}
\newcommand\titm[1]{{\usefont{T1}{tit}{m}{n} #1 }}
\newcommand\titsb[1]{{\usefont{T1}{tit}{sb}{n} #1 }}
\newcommand\titb[1]{{\usefont{T1}{tit}{b}{n} #1 }}
\makeatletter\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{28}{0}}\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{cmr} 
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{cmr}
```

Comment: `\RequirePackage{fourier}` makes the class select the Fourier fonts based on Utopia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure who labelled

```
\RequirePackage{fourier} %% fusion des lignes dans les tableaux
```

The `fourier` package selects the Fourier fonts, which are based on [Utopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(typeface)), for both text and math.

There is *no* way to get back from `fourier` by loading another font, because this package tampers quite heavily with the math font setup. The safest way to avoid it is by commenting the line in the class file, unless you want to do something weird such as starting your document with

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@fourier.sty\endcsname{}
\expandafter\def\csname opt@fourier.sty\endcsname{}

\documentclass{amu_these}
```

With either method, also remove the last two lines that serve no purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the last line it's useless but the Koma script uses sans-serif for section headings by default, so if I keep the last but one I should get section headings in serif. Am I right?

Comment: @Pino That's the wrong way nonetheless. It's simpler: call the class with the `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` option. There are other ways, but this is the simplest.